# In informatica power center I want to create one mapping and three session and query of each session is different so how I do this

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

In informatica power center I want to create one mapping and three session and query of each session is different so how I do this

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this. You need to create three sessions and change above properties using same mapping.

And pls note, you can change SQL overwrite, LKP SQL Overwrite, file name, source table and target table/schema, parameter file name.

If you want to change the SQL, just edit the session, select source and change the overwrite SQL. Pls note the SQL should have same number of columns and order like original mapping.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should actually create three mappings, each one implementing the required logic. Next, create a Workflow and add a session for each mapping. Connect the arrows to set the execution order (sequentially or in parallel). And you're done!